# the command "sudo apt remove virtualvox 6.1" has removed all programs and system

Tags: uninstall, system

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed.

When I executed the command `sudo apt remove virtualvox 6.1` has removed all programs and system. Unable to restart Ubuntu. Help, please.

Comment: When you restart Ubuntu what doe you get? An error code? Can you even boot into the OS?

Comment: Can you take a photo of the boot session to show us? Do you know how to get into [recovery mode](https://www.maketecheasier.com/boot-recovery-mode-ubuntu/)?

Comment: Yep, uninstalling `6.1` does not seem like a wise choice (explanation: the space in the command means uninstall `virualvox`, which clearly does not exist because the package name is at best `virtualbox` *and* uninstall `6.1`, which matches all the things with `6.1` in their name)... I suggest you to just reinstall the system, it's going to be much less painful.

Comment: @FerDLT It looks like you are not telling whole truth. On freshly installed VM your `sudo apt remove virtualvox 6.1` command ends with two lines `E: Unable to locate package virtualvox` `E: Unable to locate package 6.1` (so ran safe, no harm here). What else did you do?

Comment: Previous versions of apt/apt-get have a "feature" of falling back to pattern matching if an exact package name is not found - I thought that had changed recently but I cant find a changelog for it

Comment: @dadexix86 Hi, I finally had to reinstall the entire system. I just wanted to know what could have happened, and maybe what you indicate will happen. I can't guarantee that Virtualvox wrote well ... Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @N0rbert I'm not telling whole truth? Why do you say thatç? write here and not say the truth would be like lying to the doctor...